# How to place match the floor of a picture with a plane using f-spy?

Tags: camera, 2d, fspy

I have this 3D ground and "image as plane" photo with fSpy camera, but it's look wrong on the legs, is there a way to make legs to touch the ground like in original photo? not sure in which direction to search

[image: example]

[image]

UPDATE:

I mean, I believe is right with fSpy, cause all geometry lines up in camera view, I guess I'm doing something wrong or impossible with "image as plane", wrong rotation or something?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you correctly used fSpy? The point of view of the two images look different. You have to adjust the camera.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Incorrect perspective reconstruction

Your reconstructed camera in the blendfile has different orientation from the one used in the source image. Just look at the angle between the floor ad the camera's horizon: yours is totally parallel.

The narrow focal lenght of the camera is not helping either in hiding the little differences.

Here's my reconstruction in fSpy:

[image]

And here the reconstruction of the scene.

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer, I updated the question with new info, maybe you can provide some help with it as well, thanks

Comment: Oh, I talked with Ian Hubert on twitter (fantastic guy, isn't he?), and he explained me a lot, I will mark your answer as the best one, thanks!

Comment: Yep, he's fantastic. Your reconstruction looks ok indeed, but why the first picture you posted look so different from the ones with the blue floor? Are you animating the camera? Also I didn't mention, but you surely have to set up a dummy mesh to produce the correct shadow on the plane, or it will look bi dimensional in any case.

Comment: not really, I just try to place it to try to hide this effect, I think this is why it looked as from wrong perspective?
yes, I will do that, for now just overcast a lot and add distance to hide the shadow at all, so it's not really visible.